# OpenCL - clGetPlatformIDs operation is stuck after updating to catalyst latest drivers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencl

I have an issue using the OPENCL function clGetPlatformIDs and I'll be glad for your assist.
I'm using ATI Radeon 6450 HD and Visual Studio 2008. OS is Windows 7 64 bit.
Before I have updated the drivers the function worked fine but when I updated it, it got stuck.

I've put a break point on the appropriate line of the clGetPlatformIDs function:

```
cl_uint size;
if (clGetPlatformIDs(0, 0, &size) != CL_SUCCESS)
    return QList<QCLPlatform>();
QVarLengthArray<cl_platform_id> buf(size);
```

When hitting F10, the debugging pointer is not moving to the next command and it all gets stuck.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the drivers but nothing helps.

How can I fix it besides installing Windows 7 64 bit all over again ?

Thanks in Advance,

Evh671

Comment: Silly question but, did you restart windows after installing the driver?

Comment: Please provide catalyst version, OpenCL runtime version you can get this by running "clinfo" from command line.

Comment: Here's the output of the clinfo command:

Comment: Vendor:                                        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device OpenCL C version:                       OpenCL C 1.2
  Driver version:                                1124.2 (VM)
  Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                                       OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1124.2)
  
  Device Type:                                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Device ID:                                     4098